# Do i have reset service/something when banning an ip with iptables -j DROP

Tags: ip, iptables

I just run this command

```
 iptables -A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p TCP -j DROP
```

Do i have to reset a service or something like that? It does not seems to work because when i use netstat -antp i can still see the ip i just dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP connection may still be kept open until the timeouts (up to 5 minutes if I remember correctly), but the traffic itself should be dropped (eg. there should be no data flowing).

Comment: I think the thing was the iptables -A which adds the ip at the end of the list, after that i rerun it with iptables -I

Comment: That would also do it.